# Why is the real background color of the ActionBar different in the night theme than in the xml?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Why is the real background color of the ActionBar different in the night theme than in the xml? During the day everything is fine.

P.s. [Actually Day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbzGc.jpg) [Presumably Day](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxOoX.png)

[Actually Night](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3romF.jpg) [Presumably Night](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaZyi.png)

P.s. values/style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.DarkActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/purple_700</item>
    </style>

    ...
</resources>
```

values-night/style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.DarkActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/purple_700</item>
    </style>

    ...
</resources>
```

Change background color of actionbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

values-night/style.xml:

```
<resources>

    <style name="ActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorSurface">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.DarkActionBar" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/ActionBar</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>

        ...
    </style>

    ...
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because it's Day Night Theme. If you change it to Light Theme, it won't. Or try deleting the theme.xml (night) file.

Comment: I need both themes, with the daytime everything is fine, but with the nighttime problems.